# How do I implement a basic online video surveillance system in C#?

Tags: c#, video, streaming, video-streaming

I need to do these tasks:

- Client side: An application which captures video/images from the webcam.
- Server side: A server S1 which collects from clients videos/images and  stores them to a database, and a server S2  which shows the videos/images (and also a live stream) to each user through a webpage

IMPORTANT: This is the big picture, i don't ask for the whole implementation (i saw that my question is on hold :-s )!!

My standpoint is this:

I made a Windows Forms Application which captures video stream from my webcam using EmguCV,
but now i want to send the video to a server.

I don't have experience with sockets and client-server communication.

Any ideas on How to make this client-server communication happen ?

I studied this [option](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155282/TCP-Server-Client-Communication-Implementation) but I'm not sure if I can get a reasonable result

All links/ideas will be helpful. Sorry for my English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) for this type of Client-Server communication.